# Retrieve Links count based on xpath indexes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to fetch the count for a specific column in page footer.

[image: Sample Image]

The total count of links in the complete Footer Section is 17. I want to grab the count of links present in a specific column circled in Red which is ideally 4. But when i define the xpath, it gives the count as 17 as the attributes are similar in all the links.

WebElement FooterDriver = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='footer_div']"));
        System.out.println(FooterDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn_Tab']")).size());  //O/p - 17 - correct

WebElement ColumnDriver  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='footer_dv'])[2]"));
         System.out.println(ColumnDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn_Tab']")).size());

O/p -17 - Incorrect

Please help

Answer (score 0):

While finding elements along with already defined element (ColumnDriver) you should add a '.' before the xpath - ColumnDriver.findElements(By.xpath(".//button[@class='btn_Tab']")

I hope this will work for you
WebElement ColumnDriver = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='footer_dv'])[2]")); System.out.println(ColumnDriver.findElements(By.xpath(".//button[@class='btn_Tab']")).size());